# Professional Scrum Master vs Certified ScrumMaster® (CSM)

Tags: project-management-style, scrum-master

What is the different between the following project management certifications Professional Scrum Master (PSM) Certified ScrumMaster® (CSM)? Which one is better?

Comment: This is a very subjective question. If you google psm vs csm you'll find dozens of articles and discussions on the topic.

Answer (score 1):

Ken Schwaber founded and chaired [Scrum Alliance](https://www.scrumalliance.org/) and left to form [Scrum.org](https://www.scrum.org/) due to differences in values especially regarding certification.<sup>[1](https://www.scrum.org/about) [2](https://1pn8a8ult4o2bls5f2jxuel1-wpengine.netdna-ssl.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/01/Improving-Agility-Agile-Certifications-sample.pdf) [3](https://www.thescrummaster.co.uk/scrum/psm-vs-csm/)</sup>

**CSM (Scrum Alliance)**

- 16 hour course, plus exam
- 35 question, 68% to pass, no time limit
- Course content varies by instructor

**PSM (Scrum.org)**

- Optional course, plus exam
- 80 questions, 85% to pass, 60 minute time limit
- Standardized course content

Answer (score -1):

Personally, I feel CSM is better.

**CSM (Scrum Alliance)** puts more weight-age on training the candidate. The training is hands-on with lot of real life situation. The stress in on making you learn through doing it. So, at the end of the training, the concepts goes into your head and you are already ready to apply Scrum in to your daily work.

The exam is fairly easy and is taken just to ensure that the candidate pays attention during the entire training.

**PSM (Scrum.org)** on the other hand puts more weight-age on exam. So at the end of the day if you pass the exam you are Scrum Master. Are you clear on the concepts or you are a lot confused in terms of how to apply those concepts? is left up to you.